# Moving DIV with Leapmotion

Tags: javascript, leap-motion

I'm trying to use the leapmotion JS API to move a div around on a website.

I found a [tutorial](http://www.leocelis.com/how-to-move-a-div-with-your-fingers-and-the-leap-motion/) and modified it a bit because it didn't seem to be working.

This is what I've come up with so far, but `translation.x` is coming up `undefined` in the console log. Has anyone else messed with the leap JS API?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="leap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<script>
var controller = new Leap.Controller({enableGestures: true});
var firstValidFrame = null;

      controller.loop(function(frame) {
        if (!firstValidFrame) firstValidFrame = frame;
        var translation = frame.translation(firstValidFrame);
        console.log("X:" + translation.x);
        $('#box').css({marginLeft: translation.x});
      });
</script>

  <div id="box" style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid #666666; padding: 10px 10px 70px 10px; display: inline-block"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:
 1. The Leap.js library reverted the Vector class that was implemented at one point. So vectors are (again) arrays instead of objects. That makes it `translation[0]` instead of `translation.x`.
 2. You have to check Frame validity. Objects in the Leap Motion API can be invalid, which means that they are fully formed objects, but have 0/identity properties. This helps avoid lots of undefined objects, but does have a few gotchas. Try checking `!firstValidFrame && frame.valid` before storing the frame.

```
var controller = new Leap.Controller({enableGestures: true});
var firstValidFrame = null;

      controller.loop(function(frame) {
        if (!firstValidFrame && frame.valid) firstValidFrame = frame;
        var translation = frame.translation(firstValidFrame);
        console.log("X:" + translation[0]);
        $('#box').css({marginLeft: translation.x});
      });
```